# Как выбрать этот элемент с помощью CSS?

Tags: css

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]
Как выбрать этот элемент формы с помощью CSS? (который выделен мышкой)

[Сайт](http://ask-carol.com/franchises/)

Comment: что ж там выделено-то, в этой розовой красоте?

Comment: @Igor Текст, перед последним textarea

Comment: `.fluid-layout > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(11) > div:nth-child(1) > label:nth-child(1)`

Comment: Вариант с назначением класса для текста перед последним textarea и прописать нужные свойства?